# could not load library "/Library/PostgreSQL/10/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.4.so

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgis-installation

I want to make a django geolocation based app using postgresql and `postgis`.

I used the postgresql installer and stack builder (where I selected to install `postgis` as well). However, whenever I try to create a `postgis` extension in pgAdmin I get this error message:

> ERROR: could not load library "/Library/PostgreSQL/10/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.4.so": dlopen(/Library/PostgreSQL/10/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.4.so, 10): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../../lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
>   Referenced from: /Library/PostgreSQL/10/lib/postgresql/libgdal.20.dylib
>   Reason: image not found

I have tried to re-install. I have tried different versions. Countless hours of tinkering and nothing has worked. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Is the SSL library installed in the plave where the loader is looking for it?